# Registration form not registering First and Last name

Tags: php, functions, ajax, user-registration

I'm creating a custom registration form which works using username and email inputs, but when I include First and Last name fields it won't let me register.

Here is the form:

```
<form id="_wb_register" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" method="post">

    <p>

        <label for="_wb_register_username"><?php _e('Username:', 'wb'); ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="_wb_register_username" />

    </p>

    <p>

        <label for="_wb_register_user_first_name"><?php _e('First Name:', 'wb'); ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="user_first_name" id="_wb_register_user_first_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( wp_unslash( $first_name ) ); ?>" />

    </p>

    <p>

        <label for="_wb_register_user_last_name"><?php _e('Last Name:', 'wb'); ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="user_last_name" id="_wb_register_user_last_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( wp_unslash( $last_name ) ); ?>" />

    </p>

    <p>

        <label for="_wb_register_email"><?php _e('Email:', 'wb'); ?></label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="_wb_register_email" />

    </p>

    <div class="padding" style="height: 5px;"></div>

    <?php do_action('wb_user_panel_registration_form_bottom'); ?>

    <p><input type="submit" value="<?php _e('Sign Up', 'wb'); ?>" class="button-primary" /></p>

</form>
```

And here is the function used to create the user upon finishing the registration form:

```
add_action('wp_ajax__wb_register', '_wb_register_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv__wb_register', '_wb_register_function');

function _wb_register_function() {

    $return = array();
    $return['error'] = false;
    $return['message'] = array();

    //// VERIFIES NONCE
    $nonce = isset($_POST['nonce']) ? trim($_POST['nonce']) : '';
    if(!wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'wb-register-nonce'))
        die('Busted!');

    //// VERIFIES CREDENTIALS
    $username = isset($_POST['username']) ? trim($_POST['username']) : '';
    $first_name = isset($_POST['user_first_name']) ? trim($_POST['user_first_name']) : '';
    $last_name = isset($_POST['user_last_name']) ? trim($_POST['user_last_name']) : '';
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? trim($_POST['email']) : '';

    //// MAKES SURE USER HAS FILLED USERNAME AND EMAIL
    if($email == '' || !is_email($email)) { $return['error'] = true; $return['message'] = __('Please type in a valid email address.', 'wb'); }
    if($last_name == '') { $return['error'] = true; $return['message'] = __('Please enter your last name.', 'wb'); }
    if($first_name == '') { $return['error'] = true; $return['message'] = __('Please enter your first name.', 'wb'); }
    if($username == '') { $return['error'] = true; $return['message'] = __('Please choose an username.', 'wb'); }

    ///// IF USER HAS FILLED USER, PASS, FIRST AND LAST
    if($return['error'] == false) {

        $return_registration = _wb_process_user_registration($return, $email, $username, $first_name, $last_name);
        $return = $return_registration;

    }

    echo json_encode($return);

    exit;

}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///// THIS FUNCTION PROCESSES REGISTRATIONS
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function _wb_process_user_registration($return, $email, $username, $first_name, $last_name) {

        //// CHECKS IF USERNAME EXISTS
        $user = new WP_User('', $username);
        if(!$user->exists()) {

            //// CHECK FOR USERNAMES EMAIL
            $user = get_user_by('email', $email);
            if(!$user) {

                $password = wp_generate_password();

                //// NOW WE CAN FINALLY REGISTER THE USER
                $args = array(

                    'user_login' => esc_attr($username),
                    'first_name' => $first_name,
                    'last_name' => $last_name,
                    'user_email' => $email,
                    'user_pass' => $password,
                    'role' => 'submitter',

                );

                //// CREATES THE USER
                $user = wp_insert_user($args);

                if(!is_object($user)) {

                    //// MAKES SURE HE CAN"T SEE THE ADMIN BAR
                    update_user_meta($user, 'show_admin_bar_front', 'false');

                    $user = new WP_User($user);
```

When I submit the registration form it gives me the 'Please enter your first name.' error, so at least that part of the function is working. I don't understand why the First and Last names are not being registered when the Username and Email work just fine. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You're not handling the names the same way as the other fields:

```
//// VERIFIES CREDENTIALS
$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? trim($_POST['username']) : '';
$first_name = isset($fields['user_first_name']) ? sanitize_text_field(trim($fields['user_first_name'])) : '';
$last_name = isset($fields['user_last_name']) ? sanitize_text_field(trim($fields['user_last_name'])) : '';
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? trim($_POST['email']) : '';
```

Notice how you use `$_POST['email']` and `$_POST['username']`, but then you use `$fields['user_last_name']`, but there is no `$fields` variable in your code

As a sidenote, I would not use variable names such as `$return`, etc, they're reserved PHP keywords and using them for variable names is suboptimal and bad practice

Comment: Thanks Tom, originally I was handling them the same way by using `$first_name = isset($_POST['user_first_name']) ? trim($_POST['user_first_name']) : '';` but I was experiencing the same issue. I just changed them back in my original post. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

```
</br></br> 
<center>
    <form action=""method="POST"></br></br>   
        First Name:<input type="text" name="first_name"></br></br> 
        Last Name:<input type="text" name="last_name"></br></br>   
        <button class="" name="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
</center>

<style>
tr{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
```